# mocking Flask before_first_request

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

I have a Flask app and it has a before_first_request method defined.  The method loads some cached data for the application.  I am trying to run some unit tests, and the cached data is in the way.  How can I mock the method.

```
@app.before_first_request
def load_caches():
    print "loading caches..."
# cache loading here.
```

in my test file, I define a global test_client as follows:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from .. import application
import mock


test_app = application.app.test_client()
```

My test classes follow that.  The issue is that my test_app loads the cache and I need to mock that in my tests.

Answer (score 5):

You can manually remove hooks in your test client:

```py
test_app = application.app.test_client()
test_app.before_first_request_funcs = []
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised nobody gave a solution to this. I figure it may be useful to someone else at least. This may be a workaround, though I found this the easiest. In my case, I was testing a standalone function, not a method.

I was banging my head on your question too. I found that installing the python [undecorated library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/undecorated) and importing it in the file executing unit tests did the trick. Then after doing that, calling the `undecorated` method call inside of the SetUp method (before running the `test_client()`)Something like this:

In test_my_module.py

```
from my_app import app, my_module
from undecorated import undecorated

class MyTestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        undecorated(my_module.my_function)  
        # we are doing this before anything else due to the decorator's nature
        # my_function has the @before_first_request decorator.
        # Other setUp code below
        self.client = app.test_client()
        # ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not find a way to mock the function directly, but i can mock functions called within it:

```
@app.before_first_request
def before_first_request():
    load_caches()

def load_caches():
    print "loading caches..."
```